# Adobe Photoshop CC crashes through PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, photoshop

I have installed Adobe Photoshop CC using PlayOnLinux and following [this tutorial](http://evertheylen.appspot.com/blog/photoshop-in-linux).

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 3537 (here's the [spcifications](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3537_Reference%20Guide2_en-us.pdf)), I'm using a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04, with Wine 1.6 and PlayOnLinux 4.2. The installation uses a 32bit virtual drive of Windows7.

Everything was working fine, no bugs during the installation. When I try to run Adobe CC through POL, everything seems to be working (I get an error message that 3D features requires more RAM but I'm not sure that's relevant), but when I try to open any file at all, it crashes.

Here's the error Log:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x8904478b in 32-bit code (0x8904478b).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:8904478b ESP:0032d344 EBP:0032d3ac EFLAGS:00210212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:8904478b EBX:00000000 ECX:0068cb64 EDX:0032d3b8
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0032d3d7
Stack dump:
0x0032d344:  0168c9d8 0032d39c 00000001 0032d3b8
0x0032d354:  00000000 40ddc85a 072f6390 0c184af0
0x0032d364:  f5090ff4 00000000 f5067caf 072f6390
0x0032d374:  0274db2c 0032d394 0032d3c4 072f6394
0x0032d384:  0032d39c 00000001 072f6394 0c184af0
0x0032d394:  00000000 0d5a7af8 0068cb64 0032e5bc
Backtrace:
=>0 0x8904478b (0x0032d3ac)
  1 0x0168cb78 in photoshop (+0x128cb77) (0x0032d3c8)
  2 0xf506cbc2 in comdlg32 (+0x2cbc1) (0x0032d438)
  3 0x7e367972 in shell32 (+0x27971) (0x0032d498)
  4 0x7e3bfc81 in shell32 (+0x7fc80) (0x0032d4f8)
  5 0x7e3c3b55 in shell32 (+0x83b54) (0x0032d6a8)
  6 0x7e3c48d1 in shell32 (+0x848d0) (0x0032d748)
  7 0x7ec342ba WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032d788)
  8 0x7ec3499c in user32 (+0xa499b) (0x0032d7d8)
  9 0x7ec370b5 in user32 (+0xa70b4) (0x0032d828)
  10 0x7ebf54be in user32 (+0x654bd) (0x0032d898)
  11 0x7ebfc856 in user32 (+0x6c855) (0x0032d908)
  12 0x7ebfcd29 SendMessageW+0x58() in user32 (0x0032d958)
  13 0x7e269b5e in comctl32 (+0x39b5d) (0x0032d9a8)
  14 0x7e2757d3 in comctl32 (+0x457d2) (0x0032da88)
  15 0x7e275eeb in comctl32 (+0x45eea) (0x0032db18)
  16 0x7e276de4 in comctl32 (+0x46de3) (0x0032dbd8)
  17 0x7e2773be in comctl32 (+0x473bd) (0x0032dc68)
  18 0x7e27c7b9 in comctl32 (+0x4c7b8) (0x0032dd68)
  19 0x7e28362f in comctl32 (+0x5362e) (0x0032de78)
  20 0x7ec342ba WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032deb8)
  21 0x7ec3499c in user32 (+0xa499b) (0x0032df08)
  22 0x7ec370b5 in user32 (+0xa70b4) (0x0032df58)
  23 0x7ebf74b2 DispatchMessageW+0xb1() in user32 (0x0032e068)
  24 0x7ebc37b8 IsDialogMessageW+0x137() in user32 (0x0032e1d8)
  25 0x7ebc4187 in user32 (+0x34186) (0x0032e258)
  26 0x7ebc6449 DialogBoxParamW+0x98() in user32 (0x0032e2a8)
  27 0xf506aa97 in comdlg32 (+0x2aa96) (0x0032e2f8)
  28 0xf5066e96 in comdlg32 (+0x26e95) (0x0032e328)
  29 0x0169062b in photoshop (+0x129062a) (0x0032e5c8)
  30 0x01690a22 in photoshop (+0x1290a21) (0x0032e95c)
  31 0x0165aca2 in photoshop (+0x125aca1) (0x0032e9f4)
  32 0x016abf48 in photoshop (+0x12abf47) (0x0032ea28)
  33 0x00f44339 in photoshop (+0xb44338) (0x0032eacc)
  34 0x015f45f9 in photoshop (+0x11f45f8) (0x0032eae8)
  35 0x0163dded in photoshop (+0x123ddec) (0x0032eb28)
  36 0x0166188f in photoshop (+0x126188e) (0x0032eb88)
  37 0x0164bd5c in photoshop (+0x124bd5b) (0x0032ebbc)
  38 0x0167f223 in photoshop (+0x127f222) (0x0032ec1c)
  39 0x0164d49b in photoshop (+0x124d49a) (0x0032eee8)
  40 0x7ec342ba WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032ef18)
  41 0x7ec3499c in user32 (+0xa499b) (0x0032ef68)
  42 0x7ec37351 CallWindowProcW+0x60() in user32 (0x0032efb0)
  43 0x03c1768c in adobeowl (+0x2768b) (0x0032f120)
  44 0x03c2e6bf in adobeowl (+0x3e6be) (0x0032f18c)
  45 0x03c343c6 in adobeowl (+0x443c5) (0x0032f1cc)
  46 0x0071268f in photoshop (+0x31268e) (0x0032f208)
  47 0x7ec342ba WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032f238)
  48 0x7ec3499c in user32 (+0xa499b) (0x0032f288)
  49 0x7ec370b5 in user32 (+0xa70b4) (0x0032f2d8)
  50 0x7ebf54be in user32 (+0x654bd) (0x0032f348)
  51 0x7ebfc856 in user32 (+0x6c855) (0x0032f3b8)
  52 0x7ebfcd29 SendMessageW+0x58() in user32 (0x0032f400)
  53 0x03c7ef5a in adobeowl (+0x8ef59) (0x0032f460)
  54 0x03c7dfcb in adobeowl (+0x8dfca) (0x0032f490)
  55 0x03c2e6bf in adobeowl (+0x3e6be) (0x0032f4f8)
  56 0x03c343c6 in adobeowl (+0x443c5) (0x0032f538)
  57 0x7ec342ba WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032f568)
  58 0x7ec3499c in user32 (+0xa499b) (0x0032f5b8)
  59 0x7ec370b5 in user32 (+0xa70b4) (0x0032f608)
  60 0x7ebf74b2 DispatchMessageW+0xb1() in user32 (0x0032f718)
  61 0x01686c74 in photoshop (+0x1286c73) (0x0032f7d0)
  62 0x016abdaa in photoshop (+0x12abda9) (0x0032f810)
  63 0x00695568 in photoshop (+0x295567) (0x0032f96c)
  64 0x01688e44 in photoshop (+0x1288e43) (0x0032fdcc)
  65 0x01767f1d in photoshop (+0x1367f1c) (0x0032fe60)
  66 0x7b85f33c call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0032fe78)
  67 0x7b8605bb in kernel32 (+0x505ba) (0x0032feb8)
  68 0x7bc7a120 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0032fed8)
  69 0x7bc7d12d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0032ffa8)
  70 0x7bc7a0fe RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0032ffc8)
  71 0x7bc4e75e call_dll_entry_point+0x33d() in ntdll (0x0032ffe8)
  72 0xf75fd76d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf75fd82b wine_switch_to_stack+0x2a() in libwine.so.1 (0xffb32238)
  74 0x7bc545c0 LdrInitializeThunk+0x3af() in ntdll (0xffb322a8)
  75 0x7b866b92 __wine_kernel_init+0xa21() in kernel32 (0xffb33458)
  76 0x7bc54d7b __wine_process_init+0x25a() in ntdll (0xffb334e8)
  77 0xf75faccc wine_init+0x2db() in libwine.so.1 (0xffb33558)
  78 0x7bf00f43 main+0xf2() in <wine-loader> (0xffb339a8)
  79 0xf74244d3 __libc_start_main+0xf2() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x8904478b: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (222 modules)
PE    330000-  38a000   Deferred        cggl
PE    390000-  3cb000   Deferred        tbb
PE    3d0000-  3d9000   Deferred        adbeape
PE    400000- 37d7000   Export          photoshop
PE   37e0000- 3871000   Deferred        sccore
PE   3880000- 3b75000   Deferred        patchmatch
PE   3b80000- 3bed000   Deferred        adobe_caps
PE   3bf0000- 3d65000   Export          adobeowl
PE   3d70000- 3dae000   Deferred        ahclient
PE   3db0000- 3e57000   Deferred        axedomcore
PE   3e60000- 42e4000   Deferred        mps
PE   42f0000- 47d8000   Deferred        plugplugowl
PE   4b30000- 4b32000   Deferred        psart
PE   50d0000- 5100000   Deferred        tbbmalloc
PE   5b50000- 5cc3000   Deferred        adobelinguistic
PE   6480000- 64cd000   Deferred        logsession
PE   64e0000- 64ed000   Deferred        fastcore.8bx
PE   64f0000- 6687000   Deferred        photoshop
PE   6690000- 68ee000   Deferred        psviews
PE   6c10000- 6c89000   Deferred        multiprocessor support.8bx
PE   6c90000- 6caa000   Deferred        plugin
PE   7320000- 7505000   Deferred        amtlib
PE   7610000- 763c000   Deferred        axe8sharedexpat
PE   9210000- 922e000   Deferred        adbeapecore
PE   9310000- 935b000   Deferred        adobexmp
PE   9bd0000- 9c87000   Deferred        mmxcore.8bx
PE   9c90000- a069000   Deferred        libmmd
PE   a430000- a4ac000   Deferred        updaternotifications
PE   ac90000- b39d000   Deferred        svml_dispmd
PE   c6a0000- ccfe000   Deferred        dicom.8bi
PE   eb30000- eb7e000   Deferred        bib
PE   ec90000- ecd1000   Deferred        bibutils
PE   edf0000- efdc000   Deferred        ace
PE   f0f0000- f476000   Deferred        agm
PE   f590000- f889000   Deferred        cooltype
PE   ffb0000- fff6000   Deferred        servicemanager-launcher
PE  10000000-100a4000   Deferred        extendscript
PE  15540000-15674000   Deferred        wrservices
PE  15780000-159ab000   Deferred        scriptingsupport.8li
PE  159b0000-15a60000   Deferred        scriptuiflex
PE  16460000-16d45000   Deferred        adbeapeengine
PE  18bd0000-18cfd000   Deferred        imslib
PE  4ec50000-4edfb000   Deferred        gdiplus
PE  4fad0000-51375000   Deferred        camera raw.8bi
PE  6a000000-6a63a000   Deferred        cg
PE  78050000-780b9000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdc000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdc000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7d6a2000-7d6d8000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d6b0000-7d6d8000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d6d8000-7d6dd000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d6dd000-7d6f5000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d6f5000-7d6f9000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d6f9000-7d742000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d742000-7d754000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d754000-7d7d9000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d7d9000-7d7eb000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d7eb000-7d813000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d813000-7d8e2000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d8e2000-7d8f4000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d8f4000-7d9b8000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d9b8000-7d9f6000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d9f6000-7da49000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7da67000-7da6d000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da6d000-7da78000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da78000-7da89000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da89000-7da8d000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da8d000-7da96000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7da96000-7daa0000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7daa0000-7daa6000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7daa6000-7daaa000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7daaa000-7dab1000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dab1000-7dab5000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dab5000-7dad6000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dad6000-7dc0a000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dc0a000-7dc1c000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dc1c000-7dc25000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7dc25000-7dc2a000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7dc2a000-7dc38000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7dc3a000-7dccc000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dc40000-7dccc000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd23000-7dd4d000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd4d000-7dd81000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dd81000-7de1b000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de1b000-7dee9000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7de20000-7dee9000   \               crypt32
ELF 7dee9000-7e01d000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7df00000-7e01d000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e01d000-7e044000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e020000-7e044000   \               mpr
ELF 7e044000-7e0bf000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e0bf000   \               wininet
ELF 7e0bf000-7e200000   Deferred        msvcp90<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e200000   \               msvcp90
ELF 7e200000-7e22d000   Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE  7e210000-7e22d000   \               msvcr90
ELF 7e22d000-7e335000   Dwarf           comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e335000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e335000-7e568000   Dwarf           shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e340000-7e568000   \               shell32
ELF 7e568000-7e5a8000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e5a8000   \               winspool
ELF 7e5a8000-7e5e5000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7e5b0000-7e5e5000   \               winhttp
ELF 7e5e5000-7e61b000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5f0000-7e61b000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e61b000-7e729000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e640000-7e729000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e729000-7e7a3000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e740000-7e7a3000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e7a3000-7e7dc000   Deferred        liblcms.so.1
ELF 7e7fa000-7e81b000   Deferred        mscms<elf>
  \-PE  7e800000-7e81b000   \               mscms
ELF 7e81b000-7e89c000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e89c000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e89c000-7e9d8000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8b0000-7e9d8000   \               ole32
ELF 7e9d8000-7e9f2000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e9e0000-7e9f2000   \               version
ELF 7e9f2000-7ea61000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea00000-7ea61000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea61000-7eb7e000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea70000-7eb7e000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb7e000-7ecd9000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb90000-7ecd9000   \               user32
ELF 7ecd9000-7ed83000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7ecf0000-7ed83000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7ef83000-7ef90000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef90000-7ef9c000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef9c000-7efb6000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efb6000-7efe2000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe3000-7eff9000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF f49dd000-f4a08000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF f4a08000-f4b80000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF f4b80000-f4bce000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF f4bce000-f4c40000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF f4c40000-f4ca5000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-1.1.so
ELF f4ca5000-f4cf3000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF f4d11000-f4d39000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  f4d20000-f4d39000   \               winepulse
ELF f4d39000-f4d5b000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  f4d40000-f4d5b000   \               mmdevapi
ELF f4d5b000-f4d70000   Deferred        schannel<elf>
  \-PE  f4d60000-f4d70000   \               schannel
ELF f4d70000-f4da3000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  f4d80000-f4da3000   \               secur32
ELF f4da3000-f4dcb000   Deferred        mlang<elf>
  \-PE  f4db0000-f4dcb000   \               mlang
ELF f4dcb000-f4e33000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  f4dd0000-f4e33000   \               dbghelp
ELF f4e33000-f4e53000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  f4e40000-f4e53000   \               dnsapi
ELF f4e53000-f4e9b000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  f4e60000-f4e9b000   \               dsound
ELF f4e9b000-f4f3e000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  f4eb0000-f4f3e000   \               urlmon
ELF f4f3e000-f503c000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE  f4f50000-f503c000   \               msi
ELF f503c000-f5128000   Dwarf           comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  f5040000-f5128000   \               comdlg32
ELF f5606000-f5631000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  f5610000-f5631000   \               msacm32
ELF f5631000-f5649000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f5640000-f5649000   \               wtsapi32
ELF f5649000-f566d000   Deferred        dwrite<elf>
  \-PE  f5650000-f566d000   \               dwrite
ELF f566d000-f56af000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  f5670000-f56af000   \               usp10
ELF f56af000-f56dc000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f56c0000-f56dc000   \               netapi32
ELF f56dc000-f5800000   Deferred        actxprxy<elf>
  \-PE  f5700000-f5800000   \               actxprxy
ELF f5904000-f5925000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  f5910000-f5925000   \               cabinet
ELF f5925000-f59df000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  f5930000-f59df000   \               winmm
ELF f59df000-f5a00000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  f59e0000-f5a00000   \               oleacc
ELF f5b02000-f5b0a000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF f5b64000-f5ca5000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  f5b70000-f5ca5000   \               wined3d
ELF f6d78000-f6d99000   Deferred        explorerframe<elf>
  \-PE  f6d80000-f6d99000   \               explorerframe
ELF f6d99000-f6ddb000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  f6da0000-f6ddb000   \               rsaenh
ELF f6ddb000-f6de2000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF f7104000-f711a000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  f7110000-f711a000   \               dwmapi
ELF f711a000-f7138000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF f713a000-f7156000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  f7140000-f7156000   \               wsock32
ELF f7156000-f716a000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  f7160000-f716a000   \               msimg32
ELF f716a000-f7190000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  f7170000-f7190000   \               dxgi
ELF f7190000-f7200000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  f71a0000-f7200000   \               setupapi
ELF f7305000-f730f000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF f734b000-f737c000   Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
  \-PE  f7350000-f737c000   \               wbemprox
ELF f737c000-f73a2000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  f7380000-f73a2000   \               iphlpapi
ELF f73a2000-f73c7000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  f73b0000-f73c7000   \               imm32
ELF f73c7000-f73ec000   Deferred        sti<elf>
  \-PE  f73d0000-f73ec000   \               sti
ELF f73ec000-f7400000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  f73f0000-f7400000   \               psapi
ELF f7401000-f740a000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f740b000-f75b5000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f75b5000-f75ba000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f75bb000-f75d6000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75d7000-f75e0000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f75e1000-f75e8000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF f75e8000-f75f0000   Deferred        libjson.so.0
ELF f75f4000-f77aa000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77ac000-f77ce000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77ce000-f77cf000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC\Photoshop.exe
    00000096    0
    00000095    0
    00000093    0
    0000008f    0
    0000008b    0
    00000088    0
    00000087    0
    00000086    0
    00000085   15
    00000084    0
    00000083    0
    00000082    0
    00000081    0
    00000080    0
    0000007f    0
    0000007e    0
    0000007d    0
    0000007c    0
    0000007b    0
    0000007a    0
    00000079    0
    00000078    0
    00000077    0
    00000076    0
    00000075    0
    00000074    0
    00000073    0
    00000072    0
    00000071    0
    00000070    0
    0000006f    0
    0000006e    0
    0000006d    0
    0000006c    0
    0000006b    0
    0000006a    0
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    00000032    0
    0000002e    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061    0
    00000060    0
    0000005f    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    0000005a    0
    00000059    0
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000054    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0
    0000003e    0
    00000043    0
    0000003c    0
    0000001e    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002d    0
    00000024    0
    00000025    0
    0000000b    0
    0000000d    0
    0000000c    0
    00000044    0
    00000040    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000021    0
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    0000001d    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    00000026    0
    00000023    0
00000034 svchost.exe
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000041    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    0
    00000038    0
    00000035    0
0000003f rpcss.exe
    00000051    0
    0000004e    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    0000004b    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
    00000042    0
    00000045    0
00000090 CEPServiceManager.exe
    00000094    0
    00000092    0
    00000091    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.1
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.11.0-15-generic
```

I have no idea what this means. Any ideas how I should attempt to fix this? What should I check? etc.

Comment: Possibly a bug in PlayOnLinux, which should be reported on their forums. Otherwise, any reason for not using Gimp?

Comment: I need to view psd files. Gimp (and other alternatives) distort those and I really don't want to be using dual boot. You really think it's a bug?

Comment: From experience, you're likelier to get better help on PlayOnLinux forums with issues related to their installers.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is with POL (I didn't use an official installer) but thanks, I'll try that too

Comment: virtual machine is your friend

Comment: Photoshop cs6 in wine works for me!

Comment: You can try to open files via drag and drop into Photoshop or right clicking files "open with"

Comment: @DušanMilosevic I'll try that, See if it's any better. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad idea to run Adobe  Photoshop CC in wine because wine doesn't support this version of Photoshop. So what's the deal?  install other working version of it. See the rating by wine @ [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17) . Use **Platinum** or gold for better working.
CS 6 works fine under many versions of wine see http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607

Comment: Actually, I got it working. I installed some newer drivers (which suddenly popped up as optional beta drivers when I opened additional drivers). It's kinda of half-working (trying to open files crashes it, but dragging a psd to the program works). Also I don't care what's officially supported, because as far as I know wine only supports CS4 and below (which is kinda old). I would like to know if you can tell me that CS6 *is* supported or has been reported as more stable than CC (I can't think of any reason why it would though).

Answer (score 0):

From experience, you're like to get better help on PlayOnLinux forums with issues related to their installers. It is Possibly a bug in PlayOnLinux, which should be reported on their forums. If you want to view psd files, You may like [Kuickshow](http://kuickshow.sourceforge.net/).

KuickShow is an image browser/viewer with a nice filebrowser to select images to be shown, slideshow support and the ability to display the following image formats: jpg, gif, tiff, png, bmp, psd, xpm, xbm, pbm and eim. Images can be displayed either in their own window, as large as the image, or fullscreen (which shrinks images too large to display). KuickShow also has a slideshow mode.

[image]

Comment: I need to access the layers, not just view the images.

Comment: then why dont you run windows xp from virtualbox?]

Comment: I prefer to try and run it through wine for now, though I'll certainly check that option (also, I need Window 7, xp can't run photoshop CC)

Comment: then why odnt you run windows 7 from virtualbox? wine has a issue, it is buggy, it can even damage you important files

Comment: Because I want it to be faster, and photoshop generally requires a lot of RAM, which wine is [better suited to serve](http://askubuntu.com/a/113395/134047)

Answer (score 0):

I opened up `System Settings > Additional Drivers` and suddenly (I swear this was only added this week, I had a different driver activated before this) there appeared a new option called `ATI/AMD propriety FGLRX graphics driver (**experimental** beta)`, which in the description:

> Video driver for the AMD Radeon and FireGL graphics accelerators. This
>   package provides 2D display drivers and hardware accelerated OpenGL.

Activating this made Photoshop CC work for me. It still crashes sometimes (if I try to open a file through the menu for example), but if I drag a psd file to the program it opens up and I can view all the layers etc. For me that's enough, though for other I guess I can only recommend trying a different photoshop release maybe (or sending angry emails to Adobe that's it's high-time they released a version that supports Ubuntu as a native environment)